# Can there be an aqueous solution with a convex meniscus?

Tags: aqueous-solution, capillary-forces

This question is motivated by a quote from a TV show:

A detective is looking at a small vial (really a glass tube) that supposedly contains poison. Then the detective says:

> You don't have to take AP Chem to know that, in a glass container, the meniscus of a liquid containing poison, like baneberry, curves downward, but this meniscus curves upward because it's just water, right?

The detective proceeds to drink the content of the vial to convince everyone that it contains water and not poison.

The "vial" in question really was a tube.

Surely the "poison" itself was an aqueous solution. So the detective is implying that there exist some aqueous solutions with a convex meniscus. I've searched the internet looking for examples of convex menisci, and the only example I could find was mercury. Mercury in thermometers is such a well-known example of convex meniscus that every written material I could find used it as the example of convex meniscus.

Hence the question:

**Does there exist an aqueous solution with a convex meniscus?**

Comment: If walls are rather hydrophobic, even water can do that.  If cheater is in a narrow plastic tube, pumped up and down, meniscus shape can be seen pumping between concave and convex.

Comment: Also, tiny amounts of detergents or oils, particularly silicones, in or floating invisibly on top of the water *drastically* affect the meniscus. The detective likely would not have survived long in Derek Lowe's classes, e.g., https://blogs.sciencemag.org/pipeline/archives/2013/05/08/things_i_wont_work_with_dimethylcadmium

Comment: I agree with both Poutnik and DrMoishe Pippik, and the remarks. :-) Changing the surface forces (e.g., capping $\ce{Si-OH}$ bonds) make the meniscus change regardles of it's aqueous or not. I have capped them in test tubes by exposing to TMS-chloride and get a flat meniscus. By the way, the detective have drank something other than water.

Comment: This has been asked already.

Comment: Thank you for the comments! I am avidly reading that link to Derek Lowe's article. @Alchimista: could you please be so kind as to point to the question which has already been asked? I searched quickly before posting and didn't find it.

Comment: @Stef look here in Chemistry or in Physics SE... It was likely the same show...